# Why using a constructor for a .NET numeric datatype?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, collections, integer

I learn arrays and collections at the moment and the author uses the following declaration

```
    Dim locIntegerArray() As Integer
    locIntegerArray = New Integer() {1I, 2I, 3I, 4I}
```

I have never seen a Constructor in front of Integer yet. I would have declared it this way:

```
    Dim locIntegerArray() As Integer =  {1I, 2I, 3I, 4I}
```

Actually I would have said it is redundant but

```
    Dim locIntegerArray() As Integer
    locIntegerArray = Integer() {1I, 2I, 3I, 4I}
```

give me `"Integer is a type and cannot be used as an expression"`. Could anyome explain to me why we use the Constructor here?

Comment: As of 2010, the Type can be inferred from the data in the temp array literal so that even `Dim dblNums = {1.50, 2, 9.9, 18, 3.14}` is legal.  Using "New" is just the older, explicit way to do it.

Comment: The answer is; the author is first declaring the array, therefore the next statement must use the NEW keyword with initialization.

Comment: `Dim foo As Integer() // foo = {0, 1, 4, 7}` is perfectly legal (in VS2012) or even just `Dim foo = {0, 1, 4, 7}`

Comment: @Plutonix My point was that if you first declare the array as in the post, the next statement would require the new keyword. I'm unaware of any other method. Please let me know if there is a shortcut for this as well.

Comment: You are apparently talking about the last code snippet.  Yes that is not legal syntax, but it has nothing to do with declaring the array variable, but the temp literal array as Konrad explains @NathanHall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have never seen a Constructor in front of Integer yet

That’s not a constructor, it’s the `New` keyword. It is used to *call* the constructor of a type. And sure, this also works for value types (including `Integer`).

But what you are actually seeing here is something else: it’s not `New Integer`, it’s `New Integer()` – an important distinction. You are calling the array constructor, not the `Integer` constructor.

Unfortunately, VB’s syntax is muddled here because the parentheses are also used to call a constructor – so you’re right that *generally* you call a constructor on a type by saying `New T()` (although VB allows leaving off the parentheses as well, causing even *more* confusion). However, the subsequent array initialiser `{ … }` disambiguates this expression and causes it to be an array constructor call rather than a call to the `Integer` constructor. To wit:

```
Dim a = New Integer()          ' a = 0
Dim b = New Integer            ' same
Dim c = New Integer() { }      ' c = array of integers (length 0)
Dim d = New List(Of Integer)() ' d = list of integers (length 0)
Dim e = New List(Of Integer)   ' same
```

Your second code also works because newer versions of VB.NET have introduced a shorthand notation for the `New Integer() { … }` syntax. The effect is the same. Nowadays there is not really a reason to use the old, explicit syntax any more, because it is entirely redundant.

You can reduce the redundancy even more with `Option Infer On`:

```
Dim x = { 1, 2, 3 }
```

This is the most concise form. The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13tek7e.aspx) lists all possible syntax forms for initialising an array in VB.

Answer (score 1):

If you're confused why you need to use constructor for numeric data type like `Integer`, you should not. Realize that **that is not** constructor for **`Integer`**, **that is** expression to "say" **array of `Integer`** instead.

Unlike C#, this is a bit confusing in VB. In C# it is clear because array of integer would be expressed with square brackets, like :

```
var a = new int[]{1,2,3};
```

...which is equivalent to VB :

```
Dim a = New Integer(){1,2,3}
```

From above comparison you can clearly see that `Integer()` is equivalent to `int[]` which expresses an array of integer.